# Lubuntu / Ubuntu - Unable to connect to wifi network

Tags: networking, wireless, lubuntu, connection

I've been recently looking for information to fix the wifi connection on my Lubuntu machine.

I got a fresh install of Lubuntu 15.04 on my PC with a TP-LINK 8200ND connected to it. Lubuntu shows the available wifi networks but when trying to connect to any a message is displayed "disconnected - you are now offline". And indeed no connection established.

As an experiment, I booted from Live Ubuntu and couldn't connect to wifi either which is not surprising anyway.

I tried various ideas from other forums, and realized many people have this problem but the fix that worked for them didn't seem to work for me.

Linux is not the main platform I've been working with and so apologies if the description is a bit vague.

Note, I have an other machine with internet connection (the one i'm writing this from) but at the moment I can't get temporary wired internet for the Lubuntu machine.

Thank you for reading.

UPDATE#1: output of `lsusb` is like this.

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1307:0163 Transcend Information, Inc. 256MB/512MB/1GB Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2357:0100  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 that *should* be an rtl8192cu chipset 2001:330D or similar

Comment: Can you temporarily connect to internet by wire?

Comment: Is lubuntu 32 or 64 -bit?

Comment: Not at the moment, I'm currently using mobile internet and share it over wifi from mobile.

Comment: It's Lubuntu 32-bit. Mainboard manufactured in 2001.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest installing a dkms driver from ppa.

You need to connect to internet by wire and run these commands in terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192cu-dkms
```

If you do not have internet connection, you can install it this way.

Download [dkms](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu3_all.deb) and [rtl8192cu-dkms](https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+files/rtl8192cu-dkms_0.2_all.deb). You can use another computer for that.

Place these files to your home folder in Lubuntu and run in terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i dkms*.deb rtl8192*.deb
```

If Lubuntu does not have some dependencies, you can copy these packages from installation media or download them form the same mirror as dkms deb.

Packages are installed by `dpkg -i <file_name>`.

Then reboot and try to connect.

Comment: At the moment, no internet connection on Lubuntu. Is there an other way to install dkms?

Comment: @Attila Hold on, I will update my answer for offline installation.

Comment: @mchid No, nothing is needed. Tested many times. maybe in lubuntu not all packages are by default, but in Ubuntu dkms installs this way. Dependencies must be already there.

Comment: @Pilot6 build essential?

Comment: @mchid Make and gcc are already there. It is enough.

Comment: dpkg started processing the packages but it has stopped with dependency problems that gcc, make, build-essential, dpkg-dev are not installed. Is there any way to install these packages from the iso or from [here](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/)?

Comment: @Attila I updated the answer.

Comment: Wifi works. However I gave up offline installing the packages as it would have been a lot of manual work considering my Lubuntu didn't even have gcc. Instead I got a usb stick with mobile broadband and when I plugged it to Lubuntu internet just worked so I followed the terminal commands above and now wifi works. After restart a messagebox keeps popping up however saying "system problem detected" but I didn't notice any problem so far. Thank you guys for the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You will need an internet connection to do this but you need to compile the driver for the the device. The native rtl8192cu driver is absolutely awful and gets a range of about 3 or 4 meters.

**To compile and install the proprietary Realtek 8192cu driver, run the following commands in an open terminal:**

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install git build-essential linux-headers-generic dkms
git clone https://github.com/dz0ny/rt8192cu.git --depth 1
cd rt8192cu
sudo make dkms
```

For hard installation use:

```
make
sudo make install
```

instead of `sudo make dkms` .

---

**To enable this driver, use the command:**

```
sudo modprobe 8192cu
```

Finally, update /etc/modules with this command before you reboot:

```
echo '8192cu' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

Comment: If installed without dkms, it will stop working after a kernel update.

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes, it should stop working after a kernel update if you don't use dkms you will have to manually reinstall it after logging into the new kernel after completing the update.

Comment: Nut what is the point of installing without dkms?

Comment: @Pilot6 Personal preference. Also, there may be some bug fixes available so if it's set to manually install you will probably be more likely to update from git while you are at it. It's a whole lot easier using dkms for any of this kind of stuff.

Comment: I don't currently have internet on Lubuntu. Is there any other way to install the driver?

Comment: @Attila do you have another ubuntu computer?

Comment: @mchid I can install one on a virtual machine that can possibly have internet. What is your idea?

Comment: @Attila I think that it would probably be easiest to follow the method provided by Pilot6. You can just download the packages from the links he has provided and install them using the `dpkg -i` command or something similar. I was going to suggest using `aptoncd` but I think that's a bit involved since a much easier option exists. Using aptoncd, you'd still have to install the kernel headers as well and download the zip file from https://github.com/dz0ny/rt8192cu.